# Cannot get Observable to output to component

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, rxjs6

I have been working on an Ngrx app for weeks now trying to get this one observable to output to the component. Initially, I thought it was in issue with my ngrx entities and reducers so I have now tried to take this one specific call out of the ngrx framework and call it directly to output. It still won't work. The sequence goes as follows:

```
this.pomos$ = this.pomoQuery.getTaskPomos(snapshot.params.id);
```

is called from **app/tasks/containers/selected-task-page.ts** and subscribed to for output to then pass into

```
this.pomos$.subscribe(pomos => {
     this.pomos = pomos;
    });
```

a display component **app/tasks/components/pomo-tracker.ts**

```
<div class="pomo-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <div class="pomo-header">
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item>
          This is for the pomos
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
    <mat-list *ngFor="let pomo of pomos">
      <mat-list-item>{{ pomo.notes }}</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will not bind to the component and output no matter what I try. I tried adding json pipe. I tried taking off the async pipe. I have tried to subscribing to the observable in different ways. I have tried piping and mapping to it. I am completely at a loss. I am relatively new to rxjs. The observable outputs the the values to the console as you can see here.

[image]

One of the errors I keep getting is 
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

which I am sure has to do with the json object returning but why does this observable not output but all the others do. This is why I tried adding the json pipe to the output but that didn't work either.

If there is anyone here who would be so kind as to help get over this final hurdle which I have spent days on I would be greatly appreciative. [My Code is on Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/github/djr-taureau/pomodoro-it-ngrx)

To reproduce the error:

1. Login with test/test
2. From Sidenav: Find a Task
3. Search for Python
4. Add Task to Collection.
5. Hit the play button. Will time out after 5 seconds
6. Enter notes and submit
7. Refresh the page: View the error in the console.

THANK YOU in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I did some modification, and from your last step did not find any errors.

```
action AddPomoSuccess {payload: {…}, type: "[Pomo] Add Pomo Success"}
```

this is my modifications:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

pomos$: Observable<Pomo[]>;
```

and in your template:

```
    <mat-list *ngFor="let pomo of pomos$ | async">
      <mat-list-item>{{ pomo.notes }}</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
```

hope this will work! let me know if you can resolve the issue.

Comment: @m-akbari Thank you for you assistance. while it did not throw any errors, it won't display in the component. They output in the console as one would expect them to do in the component. I am completely at a loss. I created another stackblitz where I am using both a cdk datatable and a mat-datatable with datasources. and neither of them worked either. https://stackblitz.com/github/djr-taureau/pomodoro-it-ngrx/tree/new-datasource-pomo-tracker

Comment: In this one I attempted to use a datasource with a BehaviorSubject. Again it it outputs to the console as expected but not in the table: https://stackblitz.com/github/djr-taureau/pomodoro-it-ngrx/tree/new-pomo-tracker-compoent

Comment: there are some problems. it is not issue the mat-datatable or mat-list. first: from service, it does not return array (getTaskPomos) and there are some issues with undefined _id. you can omit this with: if (p.task_id !== undefined) {
         return id === p.task_id.toString()
       }. Second: create another local variable pomosSecond: any = [] and in pipe(map) do something like: this.pomosSecond.push(pomos) and pass it to the template.

Comment: this is strange, that query is not returning array, it returns Observable<any>; my solution: do not use ngrx/db

Comment: I have another solution using ngxs and firebase and i am running into the same issue. I will try now what you mentioned in the previous comment. thank you

Comment: also i gave up on trying to pull the pomos based on task_id. I am just trying to get the data table to load all pomos and then have the datatable sort by task_id within the table which is why i added that new call that pulls in all pomos.

Comment: I had actually tried what you suggested (creating a new array to push them to)  a few days ago and it didn't work. I tried it again. They are again being output as an array but when I try to pass the array down to the display component they don't output. I took off the async pipe of course and just  did ```let pomo of pomos``` but they are still not coming through. This is on the mat-list. Going to try it on the data-table

Comment: keep in mind you have also @Input() pomos. do not mix it with input variable :)

Comment: if I have a chance, I will look at your code tonight.